# Can HTML be embedded inside PHP if...elseif...else statement when HTML code contains PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a simple login page where it autheticates the credentials received from the user and creates a page with a table with all the records from my phpadmin. I am having trouble in my **authlogin.php** file. In this page, if the user has pressed the submit button in Login.html and the credentials cannot be validated (username ==qqqq and password ==== 1111, yes it is hard coded.), the page displays: an error message, followed by a link to the Login.html page. Now if the user has pressed submit from the Login.html page and the credentials are valid, the page: creates an HTML table with all rows in the database table created in phpadmin and displays it to the user.

The trouble like I said is in the authlogin.php page. The if statements are not being executed because the table I have has php code embedded in it. If I were to remove:

```
<?php foreach ($students as $student) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $student['studentID']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $student['studentPassword']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
```

The code would run, however no table would be displayed. Any help would be most appreciated.

## **Login.html**

```
<h1 id="title">Login Authentication</h1>
<form action="AuthLogin.php" method="GET">
    <div id="data">
        <label>User ID:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="userid" name="userid"/><br />
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="**********" name="password"/><br />
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" name="SubmitCredentials" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

## **Authlogin.php**

```
<?php
    require 'database.php';
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM razzam';
    $razzam = $db->query($query);
    $userid = $_GET['userid'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];

    if ($userid == 'qqqq' && $password == '1111'):
        echo 'Hello '.$userid;  
?>
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>PVA</title>
</head>     
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align = "center"> STUDENT DATA </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($students as $student) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $student['studentID']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $student['studentPassword']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php       
    elseif (empty($userid)  && empty($password)):
        include('Login.html');
        echo 'You have not entered a value!';
    else:       
        echo 'Sorry, incorrect credentials entered!';
        echo "<p><a href=Login.html>Try Again</a></p>";

    endif;

?>
```

## **database.php**

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=itec3020';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'root';

    try {
        $db = new PDO ($dsn, $username, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        include('database_error.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

## **database_error.php**

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>PVA</title> <!-- check this? -->
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Database Error</h1>
    <p>There was an error connecting to the database.</p>
    <p>The database must be installed as described in appendix A.</p>
    <p>The database must be running as described in chapter 1.</p>
    <p>Error message: <?php echo $error_message; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer is "yes". Also...that's a lot of code.

Comment: @rnevius I apologize for the length of the code, I just wanted to make sure I had everything in order to avoid any confusion. I know the answer is yes, but I am having trouble implementing it.

Comment: "The code would run, however no table would be displayed" - why? At a quick glance I see no reason why the table HTML wouldn't still work, then the loop, and within the loop the other HTM (`<td>` etc)

Comment: You don't seem to ever close your `foreach` in Authlogin.php

Comment: @James. My apologies, I just edited the code, forgot an important part in the Authlogin php. Also this error appears: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF in authlogin.php.

Comment: @PatrickQ sorry just edited that. forgot the code.

Comment: Why don't you paste the _exact_ code instead of trying to transcribe it?

Comment: Where are you executing the query? Where are you declaring $students and giving it something to hold?

Comment: Why do you have two doctype declarations? The code in your question is a lot to take in. What is the actual issue? PHP errors? White page? Displays ok but no table? (ahem) Missing end foreach...?

Comment: Try to work with with the MVC (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) principle.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments, it was partially because the missing end for each. And as @devJunk stated, I need to check what I am declaring. The issue was php errors and no table James.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't forget to close your foreach like this

```
<?php foreach ($students as $student) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $student['studentID']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $student['studentPassword']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Thank you Ethienne. That should fix it.

Comment: @Mahruf You realize that's exactly what I told you in the comments, right?

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes you did mention it, my apologies, I must have glanced over it.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to use this syntax to get your script to run.
The most important think I changed was to add the closing Tag for the foreach loop.
Then I changed the echo output to short syntax because I think it's easier to read if you use the short syntax.

```
<?php foreach ($students as $student) { ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?= $student['studentID']; ?></td>
   <td><?= $student['studentPassword']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit? What have you changed, why, etc

Comment: Or you could just add the `endforeach` that's missing. His syntax is partially correct

Comment: @devJunk Erm, no it is not. For starters `<?php` will always work, shortcode might not depending on the server/PHP version.

Comment: Which is why it's even less of an answer, the changed vesion works less.

Comment: @Doctus yes you are totally right. Need to add endforeach.